# SQL to fetch hierarchical column value along with the search column value

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL, I'm trying to fetch the hierarchical column value for a given id along with the given id displayed across all records of that particular result set.

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE user_test (id int, parentid int);
```

Input Table Data:

```
INSERT INTO USER_TEST (ID, PARENTID) VALUES (80,40);
INSERT INTO USER_TEST (ID, PARENTID) VALUES (40,20);
INSERT INTO USER_TEST (ID, PARENTID) VALUES (20,10);
INSERT INTO USER_TEST (ID, PARENTID) VALUES (100,50);
INSERT INTO USER_TEST (ID, PARENTID) VALUES (50,25);
INSERT INTO USER_TEST (ID, PARENTID) VALUES (25,18);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    parentid
FROM
    user_test
START WITH
    id IN (80, 100, 50)
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR parentid = id ;
```

Output:

```
    50  25 
    25  18
    
    80  40
    40  20
    20  10
    
    100 50
    50  25
    25  18
```

Expected output:

```
    50  25     50
    25  18     50 
    
    80  40     80
    40  20     80
    20  10     80
    
    100 50     100
    50  25     100
    25  18     100
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output can be achieved by CONNECT_BY_ROOT and CONNECT_BY_PATH clause easily.

```
SELECT
    id,
    parentid, connect_by_root id rid
     
FROM
    user_test
START WITH
    id IN ( 80, 100 ,50)
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR parentid = id ;
```